# When a game is on sale, what does the green line mean?

Tags: game-dev-story

When tracking the sales progress of a game on the market, there is a bar chart which represents its weekly sales.  Above each bar, there is a green line.  At first I though this was some kind of average, but sometimes it stays at the top despite rapidly declining sales.  What does the line represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The green line represents the sales rank of your game each week.  The rank is also shown as a numerical value beside the graph.

[image: A Picture!]

Comment: You made King's Quest?  Send in the lawyers! (But not really)